# Windows Phone 7 WebBrowserTask problem with escaped urls

Tags: windows-phone-7, browser

I'm trying to open a web page via the instapaper or google mobilizers.

So I pass to the webbrowser task the UrlEncoded url:
http://www.instapaper.com/m?u=http%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FT_Jako%2Fstatuses%2F27119375731400704

which seems perfectly fine to me.

I generate it by doing

```
serviceUrl + Uri.EscapeDataString(url.ToString())
```

The problem is IE probably unescapes the parameter before requesting the page, so I get a 404 page.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, or if it is a bug on WP7 and if there is a workaround for it.

**[UPDATE]**:
This is definitely a bug, that also got [confirmed by a guy from the WP7 team](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/72777/444191.aspx#444191).
I blogged about that too:
http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2011/01/19/WP7-Tip-Always-Encode-Urls-for-the-WebBrowserTask.aspx

Thank you
Simone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string s = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://www.instapaper.com/m?u=http%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FT_Jako%2Fstatuses%2F27119375731400704");
            WebBrowserTask task = new WebBrowserTask();
            task.URL = s;
            task.Show();
```

Works for me here.

By the way, if you're using the emulator, you'll likely experience this bug:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/d00bb0cc-bf8c-4a9e-9823-b55f589a3106/

Comment: And for using the UrlEncode... I don't understand why: my url is already url encoded. Or maybe I should double encode it because the webbrowser task is unencoding it before sending to the browser?

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely a bug.

I had problems passing Twitter statuses in French. Double escaping the URL worked for me :

```
string url = http://twitter.com/?status=testÉÇÀéçà
var wb = new WebBrowserTask();
wb.URL = Uri.EscapeUriString(Uri.EscapeUriString(url));
wb.Show();
```